# How to save listview content to .txt in SD card

Tags: android, listview

I'm developing an app that tracks some lap times, saves them into a listview and also saves them to a .txt file in the SD card.

I know how to save files to the SD, but I don't know how to get the content of the listview and convert it to an appropiate format so that I can store it.

Anyone can help me? :) Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> saves them into a listview but I don't know how to get the content of
>   the listview

If you are showing the data in your list view then you must be having the data also.So you dont need to fetch the data from listview,just fetch it from the array or arraylist you are using.

Comment: Thanks I used that method =) I was wondering if there was a more "automagic" method to do so but that worked for me. Thanks a lot